# Debian/Apache - Set up a git server + gitweb without virtualhost

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, git

I'm struggling to set up a clean and working git server with gitweb **without virtualhost**.

**Software**

- Debian 8
- Apache 2.4

**Initial setup**

- mod userdir activated
- Apache DocumentRoot is /home/user/public_html
- php5-cgi and related Apache modules enabled
- added "user" to www-data and added correct permissions

**Goal**

- No virtualhost
- All git repos in /home/user/git,
- Repos clonable/pushable from http://myserver/git/myrepo.git (ssh, http, git)
- Gitweb accessible from http://myserver/git (if not possible, http://myserver/gitweb)
- .htpasswd protected

**Resources followed**

- http://www.isi.edu/~gideon/gitweb.html
- http://www.tikalk.com/devops/setup-git-gitweb-git-http-backend-smart-http-ubuntu-1204/

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/git.conf**

```
Alias /git /home/user/git

<Directory /home/user/git>
 Options All
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted

Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.git.*)$ /git/gitweb.cgi/$0 [L,PT]
</Directory>

ScriptAliasMatch \
 "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
  info/refs | \
   objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
   [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
   pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
   git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
   /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

  SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/user/git
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
  SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
```

**/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/git.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
  <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
    Define ENABLE_GITWEB
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
    Define ENABLE_GITWEB
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfDefine ENABLE_GITWEB>
  Alias /git /usr/share/gitweb

  <Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
 DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
  </Directory>
</IfDefine>
```

Right now `http://myserver/git` shows a list of repos, but `http://myserver/git/repo.git/` is "not found" and gitweb is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

After installing gitweb via apt-get, you should run the following:

```
# a2enmod cgi
# service restart apache2
```

Then enter http://your-hostname/gitweb